# drag and drop boxes like igoogle

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I need drag and drop boxes like igoogle.com . I found this one: http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/drag-drop-panels/ but it doesn't work in IE7.

Do you know anyone that works in IE7 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [jQuery UI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) widgets in [portlet mode](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets).

They support Internet Explorer from version 6 onwards.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, may I ask you to take a look at a drag and drop related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498364/jquery-drag-and-drop-simulation-does-not-work-for-the-last-draggable ?